# In SQL, does the COUNT(*) happen after the JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a query like follows :

```
   SELECT   LOCATION_CODE AS "Location", 
        COUNT(prha.authorization_status) AS "Reqn Lines Count Approved" , 
   FROM    tabl t1
           JOIN table t1 ... etc 
           JOIN
```

My question is - suppose that I want to tally up both the counts of something, and then the "opposite" counts (i.e counting the nulls and zero's ) ; all within one query.

So I was wondering if this is possible? or does the `COUNT(*)` function only occur after we use the `JOIN`'s ? thanks

Comment: `select` happens, logically, after joins.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - Ok understood . So in my case I think I need a separate query then for the nulls and 0's . But my issue is that it will only show a column value if there is at least 1 in it.

Comment: You could do a conditional case, eg. `count(case when nvl(col1, 0) = 0 then 1 end)`, perhaps?

Comment: The engine could do *anything* as long as the result is correct. (such as: first creating a Carthesian product, reducing this by applying the restrictions. Or: only using one table, because the other table will only supply one matching row. Or: returning zero because it *knows* that there are no satisfying rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I completely understand what you're asking, but recent versions of Oracle do not technically have to perform joins at all if they would not affect the required result.

If you were counting records from a table, and joined to a table against which there was a foreign key constraint, then the optimiser can infer that the join is not required and can omit it.

Furthermore, I seem to recall that the optimiser can also perform aggregations prior to joins as well in some circumstances, if it would be more efficient to do so (for example, if joining between a DW fact table and dimension table, grouping at the atomic level of the dimension and selecting many dimension columns -- the aggregation can be performed on the fact table prior to the join to the dimension, in order to reduce the size of the sort needed on the aggregation).

So while under normal circumstances the join is going to be executed first, in some cases it will not.